# Why is UIViewPropertyAnimator not starting?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

When I try to animate using `UIViewPropertyAnimator` the animation doesn't start:

```
animator = [[UIViewPropertyAnimator alloc] initWithDuration:duration 
    curve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
    animations:^{
        _overlayView.frame = newOrigin;
    }];
[animator startAnimation];
```

but when I animate view with same arguments values (`duration` and `newOrigin`) using `UIView` method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    _overlayView.frame = newOrigin;
}];
```

everything works fine.

I tried: `UIViewPropertyAnimator` method: `runningPropertyAnimatorWithDuration`, but it's not starting either.

Values of variables: `duration` - about 2 seconds and `newOrigin` - has new value of view's `frame.origin.y`

I want to have ability to stop animation eventually, so I need to have `animator` object at hand.

What do I miss?

Comment: Do you keep the reference to your `animator` object?

Comment: @mag_zbc - yes, as parent's view controller instance private variable

Comment: Does the initializer return a valid object, or maybe `nil`? What is the `animator.state` value?

Comment: @mag_zbc - initializer returns `nil` - have you any suggestions why?

Comment: Are you sure you're storing `animator` properly? You're referring to it without `self` keyword (which wouldn't compile if it was a property), nor using underscore to refer directly to underlying variable, omitting property getter. Can you post the entire contents of the function containing the first snippet, and the declaration of `animator`?

Comment: @mag_zbc - `animator` is stored as variable (not as property) like this: `@interface MyViewController () { UIViewPropertyAnimator* animator;  }` and first code listing in my question is as far the only piece of code in `MyViewController` that I init or use `animator`

Comment: @MarekJ. I tried your code with a new project and it works as expected. Is there any special things which you didn't mention in the question?

Comment: @trungduc - I don't think there something special. I tried to init animator in simplest way and assign it to local variable to put aside unknown factors: `UIViewPropertyAnimator* animator = [[UIViewPropertyAnimator alloc] init];` but still animator is `nil`.

Comment: @MarekJ. As I mentioned on above comment, the code in your question works normally with a new project. Could you edit question with full code of your class?

Comment: @trungduc - Full code of my class is quite long and the animation is just the few lines of code that I posted in my question. I can only add that view that I try to animate is just a simple `UIView` created in Interface Builder. I use some third party libraries, which I don't suppose has anything to do with animation or views. But maybe these libraries mess with the animator? Can I somehow verify this?